# Every smooth function on a manifold defines a hamiltonian vector field.

Tags: solution-verification, vector-fields, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold, and let $H$ be a smooth function on $M$. I want to show that $H$ is a Hamiltonian function i.e. there exists a smooth vector field $X$ on $M$ such that
$$\iota_X\omega=dH \text{ }(*)$$

Since $\omega$ is a non-degenerate form as it's a symplectic form, then we can see that we can solve $(*)$ for $X$.

**Question:** *Why can we do this?*

My idea was to expand this equation in local coordinates. For example, let's do a simple example when $\dim(M)=2$. Let's choose some point $p\in M$ and some chart $(U,\varphi)$ containing that point with $\varphi(p)=0$. Also, consider some symplectic form $\omega_p=c(x,y)(dx)_p\wedge (dy)_p$ where $c(x,y)$ is non-zero (I am going to drop a subscript $p$ for a simplification).

For a given function $H:M\to\mathbb{R}$, we want to find $X=a(x,y)\partial_x+b(x,y)\partial_y$ where $\partial_x=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ s.t. $(*)$ holds in local coordinates i.e. we want to solve it for the functions $a(x,y)$ and $b(x,y)$.

Since $\iota_X\omega$ and $dH$ are linear, then it's enough to check $(*)$ on the basis $\{\partial_x,\partial_y\}$ of $T_pM$. I will write $H_x$ instead of $\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}$. Then we can see that $\iota_X\omega(\partial_x)=dH(\partial_x)$ gives us
$$dH(\partial_x)=(H_xdx+H_ydy)(\partial_x)=H_x\text{ and }$$
$$\iota_X\omega(\partial_x)=\omega(X,\partial_x)=c(x,y)dx\wedge dy(a(x,y)\partial_x+b(x,y)\partial_y,\partial_x)=-c(x,y)b(x,y)$$
So, we have that
$$H_x=-c(x,y)b(x,y)$$
The same argument works for $\partial_y$ and gives us
$$H_y=c(x,y)a(x,y)$$
Since $c(x,y)\neq0$ then we have that
$$a(x,y)=\frac{H_y}{c(x,y)}\text{ and }b(x,y)=\frac{-H_x}{c(x,y)}$$
which are smooth function. Therefore, $X$ is a smooth vector field which satisfies $(*)$.

**So,** as I understand, I can use the same approach for the bigger dimension. Where instead of $c(x,y)\neq0$, I will use the fact that $\omega$ is non-degenerate? So, in other words, if I have $H$ and $\omega$, then I can explicitly find coordinates of $X$ by solving a similar system.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely follow the question. Any non-degenerate bilinear form on a (finite-dimensional) vector space $V$ induces an isomorphism $V \to V^*$, and so this helps identify a $1$-form with a vector field.

Comment: Oh, I was trying to do it more explicitly. So, if we have a 1-form $dH$, then we are going to use a non-degeneracy of $\omega$ to find a corresponding vector field $X$. Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof that you can "solve for $X$ "is actually a rather simple extension of a linear algebra fact, which is why I'll treat the vector space case closely. Let's recall what non-degeneracy means.

> **Definition.**
>
> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{R}$, and let $\omega:V \times V \to \Bbb{R}$ be bilinear (and skew-symmetric... but this isn't really necessary). We say $\omega$ is non-degenerate if the map $\omega^{\flat}:V \to V^*$ defined by
> \begin{align}
> \omega^{\flat}(x):= \omega(x, \cdot) \equiv \iota_x \omega \equiv \bigg( y \in V \mapsto \omega(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}\bigg) \in V^*
> \end{align}
> is injective (or in finite-dimensions, we can equivalently require that it be an isomorphism). Note that I use $\equiv$ to mean "same thing expressed in different notation".

You may have seen the definition probably stated as "for all $x \in V$, if for all $y \in V$, $\omega(x,y) = 0$ then $x=0$". Well, this is exactly what it means for $\omega^{\flat}$ to be injective (and hence an isomorphism).

Now, being an isomorphism means it has a linear inverse, which we may denote as $\omega^{\sharp}:V^* \to V$. So, for any covector $\alpha \in V^*$, we can consider the vector $x:= \omega^{\sharp}(\alpha) \in V$. What's special about this vector $x$? Well, just apply $\omega^{\flat}$ to both sides of this equation and you'll see that
\begin{align}
\omega^{\flat}(x) = \omega^{\flat}(\omega^{\sharp}(\alpha)) = \alpha
\end{align}
in other words,
\begin{align}
\omega(x, \cdot) = \iota_x\omega = \alpha
\end{align}
This is why given a covector $\alpha$, we can always find a vector to make the above equation true.

---

In your case, you just have to repeat everything pointwise. $dH$ is a covector-field (i.e a $1$-form). So, consider the vector field $X$ defined pointwise as $X_p := (\omega_p)^{\sharp}\left( dH_p\right) \in T_pM$. Then, it will satisfy
\begin{align}
\omega_p(X_p, \cdot) = dH_p
\end{align}
i.e if you remove the point $p$, then $\iota_X \omega = \omega(X, \cdot) = dH$.

---

By the way, doing thing in coordinates may be a little hard, because as you can see, it involves the inverse mapping $\omega^{\sharp}$. But anyway, if you're working in some chart $(U,x)$ of the manifold $M$, with the coordinate basis $\{\partial/\partial x^1, \dots \partial/ \partial x^n\}$, and dual basis $\{dx^1, \dots dx^n\}$, then define the functions
\begin{align}
\omega_{ij}:= \omega\left( \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i}, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right)
\end{align}
and let $[\omega^{ij}]$ be the inverse matrix of $[\omega_{ij}]$. Then, the components of the vector field $X = \sum_{i}X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} $ will be
\begin{align}
X^i &= \sum_{i=1}^n\omega^{ij} \dfrac{\partial H}{\partial x^j}.
\end{align}

(you see, the appearance of the inverse matrix entries makes things not-so-easy)

Comment: Yeah, thank you for the detailed explanation! Yes, to do it more explicitly if $\dim(M)>2$ is not smart. The isomorphism $V\cong V^*$ is a really nice approach!

Comment: @eightc by the way, in my final coordinate formula, there may or may not be a sign error (because $\omega$ is skew-symmetric, unlike in Riemannian geometry, where the metric tensor field $g$ is symmetric), and right now, I'm too lazy to figure out which it is :) so there's a "fun" exercise for you to work through.

Comment: Can I ask one more simple question? How do we argue that $X_p$ as you defined is smooth i.e. its all coordinate functions are smooth? Does it follows from the definition of $X_p$?

Comment: @eightc in general an $(r,s)$ tensor field $T$ is smooth (in the sense that it is a smooth section of the $(r,s)$ tensor bundle, i.e $T: M \to T^r_s(M)$ is smooth as a map between manifolds) if and only if for every chart on the manifold $M$, the component functions of that tensor field $T^{i_1 \dots i_r}_{j_1 \dots j_s}$ are smooth. Once you manage to prove this, we note that $\omega$ being a smooth $(0,2)$ tensor field means $\omega_{ij}$ are smooth functions, and since matrix inversion is smooth, $\omega^{ij}$ are also smooth. Also, $H$ smooth implies $\partial H/\partial x^j$ smooth

Comment: hence, $X^i$ is a finite sum of product of smooth functions, hence smooth.  A more abstract perspective is to note that $\omega$ being a smooth non-degenerate tensor field implies that the induced map $\omega^{\flat}:TM \to T^*M$, $\omega^{\flat}(\xi) := (\omega_{\pi(\xi)})^{\flat}(\xi)$ is a smooth vector bundle isomorphism (note that I previously defined $\omega^{\flat}:V \to V^*$ for one vector space, but now we just extend the definition to each tangent space). "Vector bundle isomorphism" means the map is smooth with smooth inverse, (and the extra condition that maps $T_pM$ onto $T_p^*M$)

Comment: Proving that $\omega^{\flat}:TM \to T^*M$ is a smooth vector bundle isomorphism "amounts to" (I'm simplifying slightly of course) showing that matrix inversion is a smooth operation (to prove this, you of course, use charts on the tangent and cotangent bundle, and show the chart representative map is smooth). But once you establish this, then note that $X = \omega^{\sharp} \circ dH$ is a composition of smooth maps $dH :M \to T^*M$ and $\omega^{\sharp}:T^*M \to TM$. So, $X$ is indeed a smooth section of the tangent bundle (i.e a smooth vector field).